# How to install git specific version(2.7.*) on Ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu-14.04

When I run dotfiles I shown that error

`TASK [root : Make sure git version is 2.7.x]
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Make sure git version is 2.7.x"}`

Currently I use git latest version(2.14.1)
So I want to fix it by downgrade git to version 2.7.6

Answer (score 16):

I found the solution by install git with source

To install git with specific version with git source

- Download the verion that you need (ex: git-2.15.1.tar.gz)
  https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git
- [Installation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git)

  ```
  tar -zxf git-2.15.1.tar.gz
  cd git-2.15.1
  make configure
  ./configure --prefix=/usr
  make all doc info
  sudo make install install-doc install-html install-info
  ```

**Note:**
If the command `make configure` error you can install `autoconf`
`apt-get install autoconf`.

if the command `make all doc info` error you can install zlib with `apt-get install zlib1g-dev`.

If the command `sudo make install install-doc install-html install-info` error you can install asciidoc and docbook2x with `apt-get install asciidoc` and `apt-get install docbook2x`.

Comment: To add to `sudo make install install-doc install-html install-info`, if you get error `/bin/sh: msgfmt: command not found`, then you will have to install `gettext` as follows: `sudo apt install gettext`

Answer (score 1):

Purge git and the use

```
sudo apt-get install <package-name>=<package-version-number> OR

sudo apt-get -t=<target release> install <package-name>
```

Comment: Hi @Dragomir Kolev I run that:

sudo apt-get -t=2.7.6 install git  and show error that
E: The value '2.7.6' is invalid for APT::Default-Release as such a release is not available in the sources

what wrong with it?
thank you for your help

Comment: I believe you need to specify a package version, not the upstream software version:

sudo apt-get install git=2.7.0-1

Here is a link with all the versions of git -> http://snapshot.debian.org/package/git/

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it still show that error 
sudo apt-get install git=2.7.6
E: Version '2.7.6' for 'git' was not found

Comment: Sorry you must have tried the unedited version of my comment. I messed up when posting it. Try sudo apt-get install git=2.7.0-1 and check out the link in my previous comment.

Comment: Ohh it the same
sudo apt-get install git=2.7.0-1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.7.0-1' for 'git' was not found

Comment: That should work, I'm not exactly sure why it's not finding the package. sorry I couldn't help. Maybe try and google around that error.

Comment: If you figure out a solution to this problem please update my answer or post an answer of your own for future reference.

Comment: @DragomirKolev @KakadaNeang  I was trying to find the answer to the same question, and thanks to you both, I find out the solution after reading the answer and comments. `apt-cache madison git` lists all the available versions and then run `sudo apt-get install git=<version>`. The version must be a full name like `1:2.19.0-1~ppa0~ubuntu14.04.1`. But I still don't know how to get sources of all available versions. In my machine, `apt-cache madison git` lists only the latest 2.19.0 and several old 1.9.1 packages, though I was trying to install 2.15.1.

Comment: @ElpieKay I found the solution by install git from source instead,

Answer (score 0):

**Install Git 2.17.1 (to use git gui)**

prerrequisites

```
$ sudo apt install autoconf
$ sudo apt install gitk
```

Install

```
$ cd ~/<path-to-install-dir>
$ wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-2.17.1.tar.gz
$ tar -zxf git-2.17.1.tar.gz
$ cd git-2.17.1
$ make configure
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr

$ sudo apt-get install git-gui
```